# Solution of $X^2+Y^2=Z^2$ under condition $X+Y+Z=1000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As we know before the general solution of the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ in the number theory is as follows:
$x=\pm(a^2-b^2)c$, $y=\pm 2abc$ and $z=\pm(a^2+b^2)c$.

I want to know how to find a solution for the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ under condition $x+y+z=1000$?

A hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Payam

Comment: Try running numerical checks. The numbers can't get too big since $1000$ is a small number.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817848/find-pythagorean-triplet-for-which-a-b-c-1000), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103781/pythagorean-triplets-whose-sum-is-1000).

Comment: I suggest you edit the title to include the condition $X+Y+Z=1000$, otherwise it looks as if you are just asking how to find any Pythagorean triples.

Comment: thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If the solutions you want have to be integer, you can simply add up the formulas for $x, y, z$ under the condition $x^2+y^2=z^2$. For example, let $x=(a^2-b^2)c, y=2abc, z=(a^2+b^2)c$, then $x+y+z=2ac(a+b)=1000\rightarrow ac(a+b)=500=2^2\cdot5^3 $. Since $a,b,c$ need to be integer, we can let $a=2,b=3,c=50$, then we have a solution $x=-250,y=600,z=650$. Other integer solutions can be found in the same way.

Actually, if you allow real solutions, the equations will have infinite solutions. Just let $x=zcos\theta,y=zsin\theta$, this satisfies the first equation. And then, the second equation becomes $z(cos\theta+sin\theta+1)=1000$. Obviously, it has infintely many real solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I want to know the solution for integer case. Can we find a general solution?

Comment: It's quite hard to get a general solution since the formulas for $x,y,z$ are polynomials of degree 3 with three variables. But we do can enumerate all the possible integer solutions by the method above.